# Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint in titanium

Tags: xcode, titanium

I am suffering these error messages.

These messages come up every seconds and fill the console window.

I googled around and found out that it is related with iOS window layout and I could ignore the messages for now.

However the flood of the messages kick out other important messages for developping.

If I even change the error level, it comes out again.

If I mute the [info], it comes to [error].

Is there any good way to avoid this?

My environment is

- iOS 9.2.1
- CLI version 5.0.5,
- Titanium SDK version 5.1.1.GA

:log.

```
[INFO]  Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
[INFO]  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b650 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x12d6e94e0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x12d73ed30](LTR)>
[INFO]   
[INFO]  Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
[INFO]  The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[INFO]  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
[INFO]          Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
[INFO]          Try this: 
[INFO]              (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
[INFO]              (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
[INFO]          (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
[INFO]  (
[INFO]      "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x12d7458a0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x12d73d2a0.midX == _UIBackdropView:0x12d739f80.midX>",
[INFO]      "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x12d7458f0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x12d73d2a0.width == _UIBackdropView:0x12d739f80.width>",
[INFO]      "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x12d746890 h=-&- v=-&- MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x12d5effe0.width == MPVideoContainerView:0x12d72bc50.width>",
[INFO]      "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x12d746150 h=-&- v=-&- MPVideoContainerView:0x12d72bc50.width == MPSwipableView:0x12d6cc040.width>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b5d0 H:|-(34)-[MPKnockoutButton:0x12d6e94e0](LTR)   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x12d73d2a0 )>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b650 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x12d6e94e0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x12d73ed30](LTR)>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b6a0 H:[MPDetailSlider:0x12d73ed30]-(34)-[UIView:0x12d73de70](LTR)>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d75b770 UIView:0x12d73de70.right == _UIBackdropView:0x12d739f80.right - 34>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d73eb40 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x12d739f80]   (Names: '|':MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x12d5effe0 )>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d6d4b30 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x12d739f80]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x12d5effe0 )>",
[INFO]      "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d7b3180 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' H:[MPSwipableView:0x12d6cc040(0)]>"
[INFO]  )
[INFO]
```

Comment: That doesn't look good. I have no idea what could have possibly caused the output, but I'm sure one of the engineers on the iOS team could figure it out. If you wouldn't mind, please create a ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/ and attach a simple app that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I am not sure yet what code cause this error, it is difficult to make simple app though, let me try.